# program ends before reaching while loop

Tags: java

hi guys I'm trying to make a lottery program And I'm trying to get the users input to after asking if they want to retry playing.  But my program ends before reaching the while loop.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String yn = "";

    Lottery.getTicket();
    Lottery.generateWinningNumbers();
    System.out.print("\nWould you like to try again? ");

    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        yn = input.nextLine();

        if(yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            Lottery.getTicket();
            Lottery.generateWinningNumbers();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Done");
        }

    }
    input.close();
}

}
```

In my Lottery class:

```
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Set;
 import java.util.TreeSet;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Lottery {



public static Set<Integer> generateWinningNumbers()
{
    Random rndNumbers = new Random();   
    TreeSet<Integer> winningNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    int max = 40;
    int min = 1;
    int range;
    int sixNum;

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        range = max - min + 1;
        sixNum = rndNumbers.nextInt(range) + min;

        while(winningNumbers.contains(sixNum))
        {
            sixNum = rndNumbers.nextInt(range) + min;
        }

        winningNumbers.add(sixNum);
    }
    System.out.print("Winning Numbers: " + winningNumbers);
    return winningNumbers;
}


public static Set<Integer> getTicket()
{
    int userInput;
    TreeSet<Integer> getNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your 6 numbers between 1-40: ");

    for (int i = 0; i<6 ; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(i+1 + ": ");
        userInput = input.nextInt();
        while( userInput <1 || userInput > 40 || getNumbers.contains(userInput))
        {   
            if (getNumbers.contains(userInput))
            {
                System.out.println("Number already picked");
                userInput = input.nextInt();
            }
            if(userInput < 1 || userInput > 40)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid. Pick a number between 1-40");
                userInput = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        getNumbers.add(userInput);

    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println("Your ticket was: " + getNumbers);
    return getNumbers;
}
```

}//end of Lottery class

Comment: `ends before reaching the while loop` so some exception must be thrown - Maybe a NPE on `Lottery` ?

Comment: i'm not sure if there is a NPE in my Lottery class. But i included it in the post.

Comment: If you enter your while loop, you will never exit, because input.hasNextLine() will always be true. If the user types anything other than "y" to repeat the process, you will simply keep writing "Done" to the output unless you type "y" which will let the user pick more numbers, but your while loop will never exit.

Comment: @JohnG yes i added a `break;` into `else`.

Comment: Great on your Break... are you also aware that bad input will crash your program. Example if the user accidentally enters anything other than a number.

Comment: @JohnG not until you told me. Hmm any suggestion on how to prevent this?

Comment: Well ummm... you already check to see if the number is between 1 and 40... now you will have to check to see if its ACTUALLY a number before you can check its value. Lots of help here on how to do that. Try something and if doesn't work post the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Scanner Object

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

in Lottery.getTicket and you do

```
input.close();
```

This means that System.in will be closed for the rest of the program

Try passing the Scanner object from `main` to other classes and method that need it.

Comment: omg. ughh. you're right. Its in my Lottery class too. Thats why. THANK YOU SO MUCH.